# ICMP filter in wireshark not capture when i ping google

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireshark, icmp, quest

hi anyone can help me,

I try to ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but did not capture it in Wireshark version 3.6.0 in windows 10.

I use ICMP filter. In cmd, it shows that no loss and I'm very sure there is no blocking from the firewall.

[icmp not capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHOeX.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The Wireshark filter *icmp* does not cover ICMP over IPv6, which is what your screenshot is showing.  You'll need to use *icmpv6* as your filter to see what you're looking for.  Since you may have a dual stack (IPv4 & IPv6), you may want to use the filter:

```
icmp or icmpv6
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have windows at my disposal, so I can't reproduce your task, but I am doing that from my linux machine, and it works [image: icmp capture]

Maybe you did not start it with administrator privileges? Also try capturing not only wifi, but any source.